# boto3 can't delete AWS tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

boto3 [mentioned on Github](https://github.com/boto/boto3/pull/459) that they added support for deleting tags. However, when I execute the code below, it throws an exception:

```
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name=aws_region)
ec2.delete_tags(Resources=[instance.id],Tags=[{"Key": non_compliant_tag_name}])

'ec2.ServiceResource' object has no attribute 'delete_tags'

$ pip show boto3
Name: boto3
Version: 1.4.4
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `delete_tags()` method should be called on a `client` object rather than a `resource` object:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='ap-southeast-2')
...
client.delete_tags(Resources=[instance.id],Tags=[{"Key": non_compliant_tag_name}])
```

Comment: This worked great, thank you!    Strange that boto3.resource has create tag, but no delete tag, and client has both create and delete.  inconsistent!  anyway, thank you for your prompt reply

Comment: `resource` is a boto-only higher-level interface that attempts to simplify API calls. `client` maps directly to AWS API calls as used by all SDKs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it as follows in Python

```
    import boto3

    reservations = ec2.describe_instances(
            Filters=[
                #{'Name': 'tag:Type', 'Values': ['management']},
            ]
        ).get(
            'Reservations', []
        )

        instances = sum(
            [
                [i for i in r['Instances']]
                for r in reservations
            ], [])

    for instance in instances:
       # Delete the tag 'baz' if it exists
       ec2.delete_tags(Resources=[instance['InstanceId']], Tags=[{"Key": "TAGNAME"}])
```